# How do I check if x^3 is differential at 0?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

[image]

If I were to change the function of f(x) to $$f(x) = x^3$$

Can I rewrite the limit to this, by substituting the function of $$x^3$$ directly?

$$\lim_{x\to 0} {x^3-0\over x-0}$$

as compared to

[image]

Comment: uhh..context please?

Comment: You can use the first principle to derive it.

Comment: Additional remark. I would not recommend a source, where "$x^{1/3}$ is defined for all values od $x$". It is not $\sqrt[3]{x}$.

Comment: You are generally expected to go to the trouble of writing your maths out in MathJax here. Here's a reference: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference as linked images are not searchable

Comment: @ProducerofBS noted and thanks for the information!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have

$\lim\limits_{x\to 0^+} f{'}(x)= \lim\limits_{x\to 0^+}1/3\cdot x^{-2/3}=+\infty \ $

$\lim\limits_{x\to 0^-} f{'}(x)= \lim\limits_{x\to 0^-}1/3\cdot x^{-2/3}=-\infty$

Thus $\lim\limits_{x\to 0^+} f{'}(x)\color{red}{\neq} \lim\limits_{x\to 0^-} f{'}(x)$

That means that  $f'(x)$   is undefined at $x=0$.

See the graph at [wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim%20to%200%5E-,%201%2F3*x%5E(-2%2F3))

---

In contrast to $g(x)=x^3$

$\lim\limits_{x\to 0^+} g{'}(x)= \lim\limits_{x\to 0^+}3x^2=0$

$\lim\limits_{x\to 0^-} g{'}(x)= \lim\limits_{x\to 0^-}3x^2=0$

$\lim\limits_{x\to 0^+} g{'}(x)\color{blue}{=} \lim\limits_{x\to 0^-} g{'}(x)$

Comment: I am getting x^2 instead of 3x^2. where did I go wrong?

Comment: When you differentiate ordinary or when you are taking the limits?

Comment: I don't get your question. I have just started learning limits and derivative

Comment: @youcanlearnanything The problem is that I have to get your question to answer it. What is your question in detail?

Comment: can I write the limit for $$f(x) = x^3$$ to be $$\lim_{x\to 0} {x^3-0\over x-0}$$ unlike the one boxed up in blue as shown in the screenshot.

Comment: Yes, this is equal to $\lim\limits_{x\to 0} x^2=0$

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course. We have $$f'(x) = 3x^2$$ which is defined on $\mathbb{R}$ as is any polynomial function.

Answer (score 0):

You may write

$$\lim_{x\to c}\frac{x^{1/3}-c^{1/3}}{x-c}=\lim_{t^3\to c^3}\frac{t-c}{t^3-c^3}=\frac1{3t^2}=\frac1{3x^{2/3}}$$

which is of course undefined at $x=0$.